# Python&VK_API - Действие когда человек зашел в беседу

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, long-poll

Я создаю бота, и мне нужно, что бы когда человек зашел в конференцию, что то произошло, только я не знаю как сформировать сам запрос. Естественно все это по идее делается через LongPoll, кто знает как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда пользователь подключается к беседе, ВК отправляет событие `message_new`, к которому прикрепляет `JSON`, содержащий ключ `source_act` со значением `chat_invite_user`.

***Пример:***

```py
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if hasattr(event, 'source_act') and event.source_act == 'chat_invite_user':
            source_mid = event.source_mid
            print(f'Пользователь с id{source_mid} подключился к беседе')
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо большое <3